# How to use formsauthenticationticket class in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Recently i heard about  **formsauthenticationticket class**. I need to know how to use this class with user Login? If some can give explanation about this formsauthenticationticket class with example it will be very helpful to me.
Thank You

Comment: Why can't you start from Google, some blogs and articles on the internet? That is a better place at this stage. :D

Answer (score 2):

FormsAuthenticationTicket has three parameters.parameters are  string name, bool isPersistent, and int timeout.The time, in minutes, for which the authentication ticket is valid. if isPersistent is true if the ticket will be stored in a persistent cookie (saved across browser sessions); otherwise, false. If the ticket is stored in the URL, this value is ignored.

Encrypt Method

```
private string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket tk = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(stringToEncrypt, false, 600);
    // returns encrypted string
    return FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tk); 
}
```

Decrypt Method

```
private string Decrypt(string encryptedString)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket tk= FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encryptedString);
    return tk.Name;
}
```